# If $x>0$ is such that $x^{n}+\frac{1}{x^n}$ and $x^{n+1}+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\in \mathbb{Q} \implies x+\frac{1}{x}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $x>0$ is such that $x^{n}+\frac{1}{x^n}$ and $x^{n+1}+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\in \mathbb{Q} \implies x+\frac{1}{x}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Any thoughts on how to solve the above problem. Working for $n=2$ says that this result is true, but not sure if one can generalize

Comment: is it for any $n$ or just some?

Comment: You have used the formula
$$x^{n+1}+\frac {1}{x^{n+1}}=\left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n} \right)\left(x+ \frac 1x \right)-\left(x^{n-1}+\frac{1}{x^{n-1}} \right)?$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618334/use-induction-to-prove-that-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-xn-frac1xn-in?lq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936479/proving-that-frac-phi4001-phi200-is-an-integer

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827466/s-n-is-an-integer-for-all-integers-n

Comment: A special case: If $p=x^4+\dfrac1{x^4}$ and $q=x^5+\dfrac1{x^5}$, then
$$x+\frac1x=\frac{p^2q-pq-q}{p^3-2p-q^2+1}$$

Answer (score 6):

Proffering the following argument based on elementary properties of algebraic numbers.

From $x^n+x^{-n}=q_1$ it follows that $x$ satisfies the polynomial equation $x^{2n}-q_1x^n+1=0$. Furthermore, it is obvious that all the zeros of this polynomial are $x^{\epsilon}\zeta_n^k$, where $\epsilon=\pm1, \zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$ and $k=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1$.

Therefore the zeros of the minimal polynomial $m(T)$ of $x$ (over $\Bbb{Q}$) are among those numbers.

But, from $x^{n+1}+x^{-(n+1)}=q_2$ it similarly follows that the zeros of the minimal polynomial of $x$ are among the numbers $x^{\epsilon}\zeta_{n+1}^\ell, \ell=0,1,2,\ldots,n$.

Therefore the zeros of $m(T)$ are either just $x$, or both $x$ and $x^{-1}$.
In the former case $x$ is rational, and the claim is immediate. In the latter case $x+\dfrac1x$ is rational because it is the coefficient of the linear term of the minimal polynomial $m(T)=(T-x)(T-1/x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

---

This argument also proves that if $x^n+x^{-n}$ and
$x^{n+1}+x^{-(n+1)}$ are both **integers**, then $x+1/x$ must also be an integer. This is because in this case $x$ is an algebraic integer, and hence the coefficients of $m(T)$ are all integers. [This old trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576519/11619) then implies that $x^k+x^{-k}\in\Bbb{Z}$ for all $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Can this approach also be applied to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4533243/42969?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the same approach works, when rationality (or integrality) of $x^k+x^{-k}$ is known for two coprime choices of $k$. The intersection of the sets of roots of the two resulting equations can only have $x$ and $1/x$.

Comment: Would that be worth another answer to the above question?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to write $x+\frac{1}{x}$ in terms of 
$x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$ and $x^{n+1}+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}$. A domino-sum does the job here.

Put $w_n=x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$. Then, the fundamental identity is

$$
w_{i}w_{j}=w_{i-j}+w_{i+j} \ (i,j\in{\mathbb Z}) \tag{1}
$$

Say that a number $i$ is nice when $w_i\in{\mathbb Q}$. Note that
$0$ is nice since $w_0=2$. It follows then from (1) (with $j=i$)
that if $i$ is nice then $2i$ is nice also. Using (1) again
(with $j=2i$) we see that $3i$ is nice also. More generally, by induction
we have that any multiple of a nice integer is nice.

Next, look at those identities : (they all follow from (1))

$$
\begin{array}{lclclclcl}
w_{n+1}w_{n}  &=& w_1 &+& w_{2n+1} & &          & &  \\
w_{n+1}w_{3n} &=&     & & w_{2n-1}   &+& w_{4n+1} & & \\ 
w_{n+1}w_{5n} &=&     & &          & & w_{4n-1}   &+& w_{6n+1} \\  
\end{array}\tag{2}
$$

If we look at terms in the same column, the sum is a multiple
of $w_1$ : $w_{2n+1}+w_{2n-1}=w_1w_{2n}$, $w_{4n+1}+w_{4n-1}=w_1w_{4n}$
etc. Formally, we have for any $r>0$,

$$
w_{n+1}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^r w_{(2j-1)n}\bigg)=
w_1+\sum_{j=1}^{r-1} w_1w_{2jn} +w_{2rn+1} \tag{3}
$$

We can rewrite this as

$$
w_1=\frac{w_{n+1}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^r w_{(2j-1)n}\bigg)-w_{2rn+1}}{1+\sum_{j=1}^{r-1} w_{2jn}} \tag{4}
$$

In the RHS of (4), all the variables are rational numbers, except possibly
$w_{2rn+1}$. When $n$ is even, for suitable $r$ (for example $r=\frac{n+1}{2}$), $2rn+1$ will be divisible by $n+1$, so $w_{2rn+1}$ is rational also, which finishes the proof (note that the denominator is nonzero because it is positive). Similarly, when $n$ is even one can use the identity

$$
w_1=\frac{w_{n+1}\bigg(1+\sum_{j=2}^r w_{2jn}\bigg)-w_{2rn+n+1}}{1+\sum_{j=2}^{r} w_{(2j-1)n}} \tag{4'}
$$

and take a suitable value of $r$ so that $2rn$ is a multiple of $n+1$. To derive (4'), notice that $d_j=w_{n+1}w_{2jn}-w_1w_{(2j-1)n}$ can be simplified to $d_j=u_{j}-u_{j-1}$
where $u_{j}=w_{2jn+n+1}$. Then $\sum_{j=1}^r d_j = u_{r}-u_{0}$, and (4') follows.

Comment: Do you mean when $n$ is even then $r=\frac{n+2}{2}$ factorizes $2rn+1$ with respect to $n+1$?
Because in your example $n^2+n+1$ is not a multiple of $n+1$

Comment: Hm...$r=\frac{k(n+1)-1}{2n}$ has to be an integer. $k$ even doesn't work as then the nominator would be odd. Therefore
$$
r=\frac{(2k+1)(n+1)-1}{2n} = \frac{2kn+2k+n}{2n}
$$
has to be an integer. For odd $n$ the second and third term will however be odd and thus it only works for even $n$?

Comment: @Diger  please see my update.

Comment: Can this approach also be applied to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4533243/42969?

Answer (score -1):

Well, if $x^n\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\frac{1}{x^n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, so we can ask the question if $x^n\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $m$ in $n+m$ if $n$ and $n+1$ is rational, and any rational number to the power of a natural number is indeed rational, and no irrational number can be written as both $\sqrt[2]{a/b}$ and $\sqrt[3]{a/b}$, (so for example $\sqrt{2}$ is rational if squared, but not if cubed), so yes, $x+\frac{1}{x}\in\mathbb{Q}$ if $x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: If y + 1/y is rational, can we conclude y is rational?

Comment: $\sqrt {2}^2 \in \mathbb Q $.

Comment: What if $x^n \not \in \mathbb Q$?  $(x + 1/x)^n \ne x^n + 1/x^n$.